# Kubernetes rewrite/redirect path

Tags: kubernetes

I have 2 services which are using same image but configuration for those services are different. I want that whenever i request for /get_traits_similarity it redirects to /get_similarity inside of that service. Is there a way how to do it? Below is lastest configuration i have tried.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'false'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /get_similarity
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: hashingservice
    app.kubernetes.io/name: hashing-ingress
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: hashingapi
  name: hashing-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: mediasimilarity
            servicePort: 5000
          path: "/(get_similarity)"
        - backend:
            serviceName: mediasimilarity
            servicePort: 5000
          path: "/(create_token)(/get_similarity){1}"
        - backend:
            serviceName: mediasimilarity
            servicePort: 5000
          path: "/(load_index)"
        - backend:
            serviceName: traits-mediasimilarity
            servicePort: 5000
          path: "/(get_traits_similarity)(/|$)(.*)"
        - backend:
            serviceName: traits-mediasimilarity
            servicePort: 5000
          path: "/(create_token)/(get_traits_similarity)(/|$)(.*){1}"
        - backend:
            serviceName: traits-mediasimilarity
            servicePort: 5000
          path: "/(load_index)"
```

Comment: I am analyzing your issue. In a meantime please correct a typo you got in your Ingress.metadata.annotation: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/user-regex:` should be changed to `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex:` so `use` instead of `user'. Let me know if that helped.

Comment: @OhHiMark Thanks for noticing typo! But that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Also, which version of Kubernetes are you using? NetworkPolicy in the `extensions/v1beta1` API version is no longer served from 1.16.

Answer (score 0):

I see three potential issues with your config:

1. A typo in annotations: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/user-regex:` instead of `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex:` (already fixed)
2. NetworkPolicy in the `extensions/v1beta1` API version is no longer served from Kubernetes version 1.16.
3. Regarding the [Rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) itself:

   - you need to set you target correctly: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /get_similarity/$2`
   - you need to specify your host under the `spec:` part
   - finally you need to set the path that you want to be rewritten: `path: /get_traits_similarity(/|$)(.*)`

Here is an example:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /get_similarity/$2
  name: hashing-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: <your_host>
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: traits-mediasimilarity
          servicePort: 5000
        path: /get_traits_similarity(/|$)(.*)
```

Refer to the linked documentation if needed and please let me know if that helped.